# File (.PDF) para Ajax/WebMethod WebForms

Tags: ajax, asp.net, webmethods

Gostaria de saber como faço para ter as informações de um arquivo pdf (binary,nome,tamanho)

```
 public class Arqs: IHttpHandler
{

    Funcoes f = new Funcoes();

    public void ProcessRequest(HttpContext context)
    {
        try
        {

            context.Response.ContentType = "text/plain";
            var httpPostedFile = HttpContext.Current.Request.Files["Up_File"];
```

Tem como eu acessar esse arquivo atráves do meu ajax?

```
var data = new FormData();
data.append("Up_File", oFiles[oItem]);

$.ajax({
    url: 'Arqs.ashx',
    data: data,
    processData: false,
    contentType: false,
    cache: false,        
    type: 'POST',
    success: function (data) {
```

Quero passar essas informações do arquivo mais outras para esse outro metodo:

```
 $.ajax({

    type: "POST",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    url: "alt_de_dados.aspx/Atualiza_dados",
    data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
```